How to make development environment url in GCP accessible for development team only
I have two urls, one for dev. env.: dev.moocapps.com and another for prod. env.: moocapps.com
I am trying to make the dev. env. just accessible for the software developers that are working with me, in this env. is running two cloud runs: one for front-end and another for back-end.
The front-end is communicating with a back-end (that is connecting to a database) and other external services (stripe, etc...)
The problem is that whenever I make the cloud run > Require authentication

I get the error:

Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL / from this server

What is the easiest way to make this development website just accessible for few people only?

Use a Cloud Run with IAP. https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-cloud-run. Authorize your dev to access IAP (role IAP web user)

Is there a way to do it using a certificate based access and I would create a self-made certificate that only who has it installed will be able to access the website?

Did you have a look on this: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/mtls ?

Hi @guillaumeblaquiere like this it increases the cost, I think the best solution I can see is creating a dialog with a password in javascript, if you don't have it you can't go further
